# Why is voting disabled during suggested edit review?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Why can't we upvote or downvote while reviewing suggested edits? Is it there any specific reason for this design? To upvote the answer/question we are forced to navigate to the respective question. Any disadvantages to voting while reviewing suggested edits?

Comment: Perhaps making it hard to distinguish between users who are willing to review correctly, and users who are just doing it to collect badges..

Comment: @MeNoTalk, I assume the OP means you could optionally vote, but you'd still need to approve or reject for it to count as a completed review.

Comment: Do you want items with suggested edits to get more votes than items without?

Comment: I believe the idea is to limit voting from the extra views that come from the review queues as that unfairly skews voting towards those posts.  If I am not mistaken "First Posts" and "Late Answers" are the only queues with voting enabled and that's because that is the purpose of those queues.

Answer (score 2):

Why? So that the reviewers can focus on the actual goal: reviewing the suggested edit itself.

Adding more elements has big chance of distracting the reviewers, who many times don't have much time to begin with.

That's why there are no actions at all: no flagging, no comments, etc.

If anyone want to do any of these, it's easy enough to middle/CTRL-click the post title to reach the post on its own page, then go wild with actions. :)

<sub>*All of the above is my own personal opinion, not official response from SE*</sub>